# How to stop an audio from playing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Sorry about the confusing title, but I have the following problem. I am working on a site where people can press a link and play a song, but in a page where there are multiple links (for playing songs), users can press all the links and all the songs start to play at the same time. So, this makes the current selected song difficult to hear.

So, what I am trying to do is, to cancel / stop the last playing song when a new link is pressed. Here is my code:

```
<div class='content'> 
    click <a href="javascript:play_wav('h');" class='h play-audio'> here </a> 
    to play the song
</div>


function play_wav(audio_name)
{
    var src = document.querySelector('.'+audio_name).innerHTML = 
        "<audio src='audio/"+classs+".wav' class='audio_"+audio_name+"'>";
    document.querySelector('.audio_'+audio_name).play();  
}
```

Don't mind the bad quality, but as you can see, when the link is pressed, the DOM integrates an `<audio src='audio/foo.wav' class='audio_foo"'>`
then the script finds the `audio_foo` class and plays the songs.

But when another link is pressed, how do I reset the DOM to it's original state or just stop it from playing a previously started song?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.audio_'+audio_name).stop()`?

Comment: And re-word the question title. It has nothing to do with the question content.

Comment: @MelanciaUK But, that would only stop the current link you are clicking on. Not the audio that was being played.

Comment: What I meant is that there is a method to stop the playback. It's the `.stop()` method. You need to work out your script logic to keep track of what's being played.

Comment: You'd do it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/F5mMr/1/**

Comment: @adeneo Perfect. A great way to learn JS at the same time

Comment: @adeneo I just tried your code, because I found it way more elegant, and as a tool to learn js the right way, but the code only stops a second the song from playing, until the current one finished. It does not stop the playing audio to start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a reference to the currently playing song.

```
var current_audio;

function play_wav(audio_name)
{
  if (current_audio)
  {
    current_audio.stop();
  }

  var src = document.querySelector('.'+audio_name).innerHTML = "<audio src='audio/"+classs+".wav' class='audio_"+audio_name+"'>";
  current_audio = document.querySelector('.audio_'+audio_name);
  current_audio.play();
}
```

I've never used audio in javascript before, but I'm assuming there is a `stop` function if there is a `play` function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function play_wav(audio_name) {
  // List of all audio tags
  var audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio')
  //Iterate over all
  for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
    var audio = audios[i]
    // Stop playing
    audio.pause()
    // Remove node
    audio.parentNode.removeChild(audio)
  }

  var audio = document.querySelector('.'+audio_name)
  audio.innerHTML = "<audio src='audio/"+classs+".wav' class='audio_"+audio_name+"'>"
  audio.querySelector('audio').play()
}
```